# how can I use js variable in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm using 'convertHangul()' method which is in java object in html with thymeleaf.
I already checked it works but there is some problem in case of with js variable.

It works successfully without js variable as below.

```
let tmp = '[[${@customUtil.convertHangul(3333221)}]]';
```

but this case, it doesn't work.

```
let txt = $('#money').text();
let tmp ='[[${@customUtil.convertHangul('+txt+')}]]';
```

I got a thymeleaf parsing exception. I think there is some syntax error.

how can I use js variable in thymeleaf?

Comment: You are not able to do this. Thymeleaf renders the page before it's delivered to a client (web browser); When the page loaded into the browser, and JS able to run, Thymeleaf already has done and you are dealing with regular HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use thymeleaf with your Java-Script code, you need to use -
`th:inline="javascript"` with your `<script>` tag.
So your code will look something like this -

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    ...
       //your code
    ...
</script>
```

Refer the thymeleaf official documentation in order to get to know more about thymeleaf with javascript -

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining